# is it a good practice to use string manipulation in c#

Tags: string, c#-4.0, split, substring, coding-style

I need to extract parts of string, I found 2 methods which one is better in coding practices and is it a good coding practice to use string manipulation? is there any other way in which this task can be done?

```
string test = "name.jpg_add1_srcimages_pagetest.htm";
string img_name = test.substring(0,str.LastIndexOf("_add"));
//or 
string[] img_prop = test.Split('_');
string img_n = img_prop[0]
```

Comment: it is good to use split function of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance string.Split is optimized.